# Unable to unsubscribe while running observables in a foreach method

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am iterating an array of items via foreach method. Each item executes two http calls which are nested. I am unable to unsubscribe the observables when the loop finishes. Could you please provide an solution for this

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;

constructor(...) {
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
}

ngOnChanges(): void {

    //this.fileList is an array of ids

    this.fileList.forEach((id) => {

        this.getData(id).subscribe((res:any) => {
            console.log(res)
        })

    });

    getData(id): Observable<any> {

        return this.fileService.getFileDetails(id).pipe(take(1),
        mergeMap(data => {
            if(data != undefined) {
            return this.fileService.downloadFile(data[0].path)
            }
        }))

    }

}

ngOnDestroy() {

    this._unsubscribeAll.next();
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do as simple as this:

```js
const subscriptions: Subscription[] = []

this.fileList.forEach((id) => {

    this.subscriptions.push(
        this.getData(id).subscribe((res: any) => {
            console.log(res)
        })
    )

});

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(s => s.unsubscribe())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating a single subscription by mapping `fileList` into an array of observables and waiting for them all to complete using `forkJoin`, as demonstrated below:

```js
private subscription: Subscription;

public ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.subscription = this.getData().subscribe((x:any[]) => { });
}

public getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    const observables: Observable<any>[] = this.fileList.map(id => {
      return this.fileService.getFileDetails(id).pipe(
        first(),
        filter(data => data != undefined),
        mergeMap(data => this.fileService.downloadFile(data[0].path))
      )
    );

    return forkJoin(observables);
}

public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Subscription class in RxJS has an add() method that
let 's you add subscriptions. All added subscriptions will be unsubscribed when you call unsubscribe() on the root subscription.

```
// Create a new subscription
   const subscription = new Subscription();

// Subscribe to some observables
// and add them to the subscription

    this.fileList.forEach((id) => {
        const sub = this.getData(id).subscribe((res:any) => {
            console.log(res)
        });
       subscription.add(sub);
    });

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
      this.subscription.unsubscribe();
   }
```